# Crystal report viewer asking parameters again when clicking on the tool bar (sub Report anything) and in return showing same main page

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

It is an old application
it showing crystal report on the Web page but the problem is that when I am clicking on anything it is asking for parameters again but showing the same report I have no idea how to do this because if I am clicking on sub Report same asking for parameters and showing the same report

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {

```
        var p = Request.QueryString["P"].ToString();
        var appId = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["appId"].ToString());
        var HE = new HIVAIDSEntities();
        var app = HE.ApplicatioNames.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Hivrp_app_name_pk == appId);



        //SQLReport report = new SQLReport();
        var report = new ReportDocument();
        //   Application.StartupPath 
        report.Load(filename: Server.MapPath(p));
        //Get SQL Server Details
        string zServer = app.Hivrp_server_name;
        string zDatabase = app.Hivrp_database_name;
        string zUsername = app.Hivrp_user_id;
        string zPassword = app.Hivrp_password;

        var ciReportConnection = new ConnectionInfo
        {
            ServerName = zServer,
            DatabaseName = zDatabase,
            UserID = zUsername,
            Password = zPassword
        };

        //TableLogOnInfo crTableLogoninfo = new TableLogOnInfo();
        //Assign data source details to tables

        foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table table in report.Database.Tables)
        {

            table.LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo = ciReportConnection;
            table.ApplyLogOnInfo(table.LogOnInfo);

        }


        //Assign data source details to the report viewer
        if (this.CrystalReportViewer1.LogOnInfo != null)
        {
            TableLogOnInfos tlInfo = this.CrystalReportViewer1.LogOnInfo;
            foreach (TableLogOnInfo tbloginfo in tlInfo)
            {
                tbloginfo.ConnectionInfo = ciReportConnection;
            }
        }
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report;
        CrystalReportViewer1.ToolPanelView = CrystalDecisions.Web.ToolPanelViewType.None;
        CrystalReportViewer1.DisplayPage = true;

        CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
        Session["ReportDocument"] = report;
    }
    else
    {
        ReportDocument doc = (ReportDocument)Session["ReportDocument"];
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = doc;
        CrystalReportViewer1.ToolPanelView = CrystalDecisions.Web.ToolPanelViewType.None;
        CrystalReportViewer1.DisplayPage = true;

        CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just changed Page_Load function to Page_Init and everything is working fine :)